# How to apply currency validation to text box using a regular expression?

Tags: html, jquery, css, forms, validation

Consider this form:

```html
<form>
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter no. of employee" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');" required/>
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter Salary" required/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

I want a regular expression validation for **Enter salary** text feild with following:

- The salary should be  separated by commas like this format 1,00,000
- It should not take any other  input except numbers like in the case
  of "Enter no. of employee" field

Comment: i want this to work something like this:https://codepen.io/akalkhair/pen/dyPaozZ

but without $ and decimal sign with a simple regular expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution for my problem:

**Indian currency:**

```
onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '').replace(/\B(?=(?:(\d\d)+(\d)(?!\d))+(?!\d))/g, ',');"
```

**US Currency:**

```
onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '').replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');"
```

**Working solution:**

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter no. of employee" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');" required/>
    <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter Salary" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '').replace(/\B(?=(?:(\d\d)+(\d)(?!\d))+(?!\d))/g, ',');" placeholder="Enter Salary" required/>
    <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

- The salary should be separated by commas like this format 1,00,000
- It should not take any other input except numbers like in the case of
  "Enter no. of employee" field.

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter no. of employee" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');" required/>
  <input type="text" value="" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '').replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');" placeholder="Enter Salary" required/>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: not working..
can you explain what you want to achieve ?

Comment: Try supplying incorrect salary information and click on "Submit" button.

Comment: i want this to work something like this:  https://codepen.io/akalkhair/pen/dyPaozZ

but without $ and decimal sign with a simple regular expression

Comment: I modify the snippet as per your requirement please check, also I took the reference from the link which you shared above. It should work now. Thanks for correcting! (actually you have not mentioned the flow which you want in your OG post)

Comment: I appreciate your effort and time but this is not what i want.
I want a single line regular expression.. the same way you can see on the first text field to enter no. of employees...
oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');"

Comment: I modified the code please check. Finally I understood what you actually want. (I hope so this is what you want).

Comment: this is so close on what i want..
the only thing left is the commas..
currently they are set to 3 places.. 100,000 but i want 1,00,000